# InvalidOperationException with Xamarin and AWS FB Login

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook, amazon-web-services, xamarin

I am running a [sample](https://github.com/awslabs/aws-sdk-net-samples/tree/master/XamarinSamples/DynamoDB) Xamarin forms app, whihc is demoing the use of the AWS SDK. When the app simulator launches, I get a blank screen with a Login to Facebook button, which when clicked throws the following `Unhandled Excetion:`

> Foundation.MonoTouchException: Objective-C exception thrown. Name: InvalidOperationException Reason: fb is not registered as a URL scheme. Please add it in your Info.plist

Not really sure what to do to remedy this, what should I add to `Info.plist` ?

It is the `HandleFacebookLoginClicked()` Function in [this](https://github.com/awslabs/aws-sdk-net-samples/blob/master/XamarinSamples/DynamoDB/ContactManager.iOS/FacebookLoginButtonRenderer.cs) file which is throwing the error.

Comment: did you follow https://components.xamarin.com/gettingstarted/facebookios and setup facebook for xamarin ios?

Comment: @Karthik I am not sure how to do this, info.plist is opened in a form, not as a text document in both Xamarin, Visual Studio and XCode, so how can I add that text?

Comment: You can just open it using a text editor.